# No Class Def Exception with ActionListener only with .jar file

Tags: java, swing, jar, jframe, noclassdeffounderror

So my program works fine when I compile it but then when I try to export it as a jar, nothing shows up in my JFrame, I tried compiling it with command prompt and got:

```
C:\Users\Josh\Desktop>java -jar C:\Jar\jar.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: StartFrame$1
    at StartFrame.startMethod(StartFrame.java:44)
    at StartFrame.main(StartFrame.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: StartFrame$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

StartFrame line 44 points to the actionlistener for my enter button, line 44 is as follows:

```
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            addBracket();
        }
    });
```

I was wondering what was causing the blank screen when I export my program to a .jar file, the enterbutton shows up fine when I compile the program normally.

Comment: Did you package the dependencies jar files together with the exported jar before running it?

Comment: `StartFrame$1` is the anonymous inner class in the Jar file? What is the output of `jar -tvf jar.jar`?

Comment: Would I need to package a dependency for a JButton or action listener?

Comment: `when I try to export it as a jar` How are you creating the jar?

Comment: Creating the .jar file through BlueJ

Comment: StartFrame$1 is the anonymous class for the actionlistener

Comment: @Josh the action listener

Comment: *"StartFrame$1 is the anonymous class for the actionlistener"* I guessed that. Now answer my question!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by jar -tvf jar.jar, I tried typing it in command prompt but it told me it was an unrecognized command

Comment: Tip: Add @SamuelKok (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"I'm not sure what you mean by jar -tvf jar.jar, .."* Why did I need to ask a 2nd time in order to get that information? Do you think we are psychic? Do you think we enjoy playing 20 questions? If you want answers, better smarten up. - It seems the JDK is not on the command class path. Type the entire `path/to/the/jar` command.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I actually figured it out, I created the jar with IntelliJ instead of BlueJ and everything works, it turns out I had imported a JSON parser sometime earlier and it broke my jar even though I wasn't using it, thanks for the help everyone, turns out I didn't package the dependencies together. Sorry for the trouble.